# how to draw a chat bubbles use Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I find to more sample to draw chat bubbles use CSS, but I can't find how to draw this bubbles, I have no idea about the angle of top

[image]

---

first, thanks, all advice in these question, I have a mistake for not upload my codes that I tried.

finally, thanks, @holden answer that is correct, and I upload my codes after I got the idea how to use a triangle with :after, If anyone has the same problem, I think it can give you some idea :)

---

if you want to edit my final code, you can go to the online editor (https://jsfiddle.net/ypgou3wy/)

```css
/* layout */

body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* main */

@mixin tringleWithInCircule() {
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 37px 43px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.logo1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 37px 43px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

.logo2 {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.logo2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 37px 43px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

.logo3 {
  transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
}

.logo3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 37px 43px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

.logo4 {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.logo4:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 37px 43px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo logo1">

</div>

<div class="logo logo2">

</div>

<div class="logo logo3">

</div>

<div class="logo logo4">

</div>
```

Comment: Please add codes of what you have tried.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that but this will help you

https://codepen.io/Founts/pen/gmhcl

Comment: It can be reached in different ways. For simple shapes i prefer just working with borders.
In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5g6kb8x3/1/ i shaped a circle with borders propriety and added the triangle with :after.
In this exemple you can modify the shape according to your needs just modifing the values in px.
As pointed out before, is anyway difficolt bring you in the right path if we can't see any code by your side...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't upload my code when I ask the question because I have no idea to modify the triangle, ex. draw a triangle can use  border-color with border-radius

Comment: @holden thanks, your answer is I want to display, may I mark your advice to the answer?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS should get you started, just play around with it:

```
#speech-bubble {
   width: 120px; 
   height: 80px; 
   background: blue;
   position: absolute;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   border-radius: 10px;
}
#speech-bubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 3px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid blue;
   border-bottom: 23px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Here is the [JS Bin demo](http://output.jsbin.com/fuhatiqace/1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that is to create Speech bubble. Also you can change the variables and the pointer position [here](https://leaverou.github.io/bubbly/)

```
.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #00aabb;
    border-radius: .4em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #00aabb;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```